# Barra de Progresso em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Ola pessoal como fazer barra de progresso em javascript igual a da imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Precisa que o progresso seja exatamente igual o que está na imagem (com todas essas cores sortidas)?

Comment: Você colocou a tag [jquery-ui] na sua pergunta. Então tomei a liberdade de te mostrar esse [link](https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/).  Já tem pronto no jQueryUI

Comment: O cor vermelho nao precisa, pode ser duas cores verde e o azul...

Comment: Esta barra você quer utilizar somente html, css e javascript sem plugins ? se sim, onde deseja utiliza-la e como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem uma série de libraries que fazem isso. Recomendo você utiliza-las para não reinventar a roda.

1. https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/
2. Usando jQueryUI https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/
3. Uma opção mais simples https://github.com/tinacious/goalProgress

Enfim, existem centenas desses plugins/libraries para vocês usar.

Caso você queria mesmo criar a sua usando javascript puro ou jquery vai dar um certo trabalho sem necessidade, mas posso te ajudar.

Você pode criar a sua própria baseada em uma que já existe.

Por exemplo https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-multi-bar

Para uma implementação JavaScript pura e sem usar nenhuma biblioteca, aqui esta uma implementação bem simples https://jsfiddle.net/ss18yedy/9/ use ela como base e evolua até uma solução final que seja o que você precisa.

Comment: Ola Erick Gallani, gostaria mesmo de fazer um sem utilização dessas bibliotecas...

Comment: @RadyBatalha legal, então vamos lá. Comece por aqui http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp e vamos incrementando a medida que você for desenvolvendo para chegar até onde você quer.

Comment: aqui esta o link: https://jsfiddle.net/hrtlopes/ss18yedy/

Comment: @RadyBatalha aqui esta uma implementação bem simples https://jsfiddle.net/ss18yedy/5/ você pode continuar a partir dela

Comment: Obirgado mesmo, @Erick Gallani..

Comment: @RadyBatalha sem problemas. Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta para ajudar os demais usuários do stackoverflow.

Comment: @RadyBatalha uma versão melhorzinha https://jsfiddle.net/ss18yedy/9/